# Matplot-lib 2.2.3 plots no longer working in my Python 3.7 Spyder console

Tags: matplotlib

I completed a course in Data Visualization and submitted a number of exercises using Matplot-lib which worked fine using version 2.2.3, with Python 3.7 in a Anaconda Spyder console.  I have since moved on to a Machine Learning course and starting to run those exercises by plots will not display in the Console any longer.  The given code in the ML course works fine in a Jupyter notebook:

MESSAGE after code is run:
"IPython.core.display.Javascript object"
"IPython.core.display.HTML object"

This same code works fine in a Jupyter notebook and produces a nice chart? I am trying to work and gain proficiency in both environments but don't know what this message means, or how to change the code to again produce charts?

I went back to my previous course and code that worked there now also returns a message but no plots. I think this may be a version problem.  I am trying to install Matplot-lib 3.0.2 from within Anaconda cloud but having troubles with this process.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

np.random.seed(0)
n = 15
x = np.linspace(0,10,n) + np.random.randn(n)/5
y = np.sin(x)+x/6 + np.random.randn(n)/10

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, random_state=0)

# You can use this function to help you visualize the dataset by
# plotting a scatterplot of the data points
# in the training and test sets.
def part1_scatter():
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    get_ipython().magic('matplotlib notebook')
    plt.figure()
    plt.scatter(X_train, y_train, label='training data')
    plt.scatter(X_test, y_test, label='test data')
    plt.legend(loc=4)


# NOTE: Uncomment the function below to visualize the data, but be sure 
# to **re-comment it before submitting this assignment to the autograder**.   

part1_scatter()
```

I expect to see a scatter plot of randomly generated data.  Instead I got the following lines/messages in the output line:

```
"<IPython.core.display.Javascript object>"
"<IPython.core.display.HTML object>"
```

Comment: Did you by chance update jupyter recently? What happens if you call `plt.show()` at the point where you want to show the figure?

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding.  I tried this on a number of different files and it gives the same result. I did just updated to latest matplot-lib 3.0.2

Comment: This should be independent of matplotlib. You are trying to use the `'matplotlib notebook'` backend in the IPython console which is not supported.

Comment: Thanks, I discovered that in the wee hours...removed get_ipython().magic('matplotlib notebook') and it works.

Comment: not familiar with get_ipython().magic('matplotlib notebook')  - is  only supported for Jupyter notebooks?

Comment: Yes, it requires a browser which is capable of showing html and javascript (the objects that are otherwise only shown with their text representation).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I am new to Stackoverflow as well and navigating all these systems has been a bit overwhelming at times.